# Ошибка при добавлении в массив Vue

Tags: vue.js

подскажите почему ошибка **this is undefined** ?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="addRow">Добавить в новый массив</button>
    <pre><code>{{ newRole }}</code></pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        role: [{
            name: 'Alex',
            id: '1'
          },
          {
            name: 'Sveta',
            id: '2'
          },
        ],
        newRole: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addRow() {
        this.role.forEach(function(value, key) {
          this.newRole.push(value.id);
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в [контексте](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind). Используйте [стрелочную функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) в качестве `callback` для `forEach`, чтобы использовать в нем `this` для экземпляра `vue`.

```
addRow() {
  this.role.forEach((value, key) => {
    this.newRole.push(value.id);
  });
}
```

> Стрелочные функции особенные: у них нет своего «собственного» `this`.
>   Если мы используем `this` внутри стрелочной функции, то его значение
>   берётся из внешней «нормальной» функции. Это является особенностью стрелочных функций. Они полезны, когда мы на самом деле не хотим иметь отдельное значение `this`, а хотим брать его из внешнего контекста.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      role: [{
          name: 'Alex',
          id: '1'
        },
        {
          name: 'Sveta',
          id: '2'
        },
      ],
      newRole: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.role.forEach((value, key) => {
        this.newRole.push(value.id);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-success" @click="addRow">Добавить в новый массив</button>
  <pre><code>{{ newRole }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Идеально,спасибо